# Phone is Stuck in Boot Loop With Recovery Not Accessible

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop

I have a Tecno P5 and wanted to flash ClockworkMod Recovery onto it. I used **Recovery-Tools** to do this with the file [TECNO-P5_130916__recovery_140106-193223.img](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bandhktedj8adks/TECNO-P5_130916__recovery_140106-193223.img). The process completed and I was prompted to boot into recovery. The reboot did not complete.

I can get into the boot menu (Volume Up + Power), but when I select **Recovery** mode or **Normal** mode the phone gets into a boot loop. **Fastboot** mode works and I can connect from Windows 7. The result of `fastboot devices` is "***mt6572v1_phone fastboot***"

No other Fastboot commands are having any observable effect apart from `fastboot flash recovery TECNO-P5_130916__recovery_140106-193223.img` which results in the error "***Security deny - Err:0x2017***".

`fastboot oem unlock` just hangs at "***...***"

Is there a tool that can either unlock the bootloader or reset the phone to factory settings so it can boot normally?

Comment: You could re-flash the stock recovery again from fastboot, but you'll need to find the image from the manufacturer or from someone who's taken a backup.

Comment: @DanHulme I have a zip that I believe is a backup of stock ROM meant for unbricking. I tried flashing the recovery from that, but I still get "Security deny - Err:0x2017". If only I could get pas that error...

Comment: Try downloading the latest adb and fastboot tools. Some fastboot tools hang while unlocking bootloader